# Unable to control structlog using logging

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver, python-logging, structlog

I'm unable to disable logging which is by default turned on via `structlog`

Here's my code below:

Input file contain:

```
5418531366
5418531367
```

```
import asyncio
import pathlib
import sys
from arsenic import get_session, errors
from arsenic.browsers import Firefox
from arsenic.services import Geckodriver
from aiofile import async_open
from termcolor import colored
import os


async def browse(numbers, baseurl):
    limit = asyncio.Semaphore(3)

    async def call(num):
        async with limit, get_session(Geckodriver(log_file=os.devnull), Firefox(**{'moz:firefoxOptions': {'args': ['-headless']}})) as session:
            await session.get(baseurl)
            fixednum = await session.wait_for_element(10, '#attContent_txtAccessNumber')
            await fixednum.send_keys('8778791867')
            dynnum = await session.wait_for_element(10, '#attContent_txtPIN')
            await dynnum.send_keys(num)
            goal = await session.get_element('#attContent_btnSubmit')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
            await goal.click()

            try:
                await session.wait_for_element_gone(10, '#attContent_btnSubmit')
                return str(num)
            except errors.ArsenicTimeout:
                return False

    tasks = [call(n) for n in numbers]
    async with async_open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
        for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            task = await task
            if task:
                print(f"\nAvailable -- > {colored(task,'green')}\n")
                await f.write(task + "\n")


async def amain():
    baseurl = "https://www.virtualprepaidminutes.com/ATT_prepaid_calling_cards_refill_online.aspx"
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        return f"Usage: python {pathlib.Path(__file__).name} `InputFile`"

    try:
        numbers = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1]).read_text(
            encoding="utf8").splitlines()
        await browse(numbers, baseurl)

    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(f"File {e.filename} is not exist!")


def main():
    return asyncio.run(amain())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

The code works fine except that i wish to get rid of the log displayed in terminal as I've tried multiple ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using the following function:

```
def set_arsenic_log_level(level = logging.WARNING):
    logger = logging.getLogger('arsenic')


    def logger_factory():
        return logger

    structlog.configure(logger_factory=logger_factory)
    logger.setLevel(level)
```

Credit to - > [Github Answer](https://github.com/HDE/arsenic/issues/35#issuecomment-451540986)

Answer (score 0):

Your example contains neither `structlog` nor `logging` configuration nor a call to either – so it's kinda difficult to help you. I'm gonna take a wild guess and assume that the log entries are coming from arsenic.

If you want to control structlog via stdlib as your subject insinuates, you have to configure it to integrate with stdlib. That is documented here: https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html#suggested-configurations

Afterwards, structlog will log through stdlib and thus respect stdlib's log levels.

Comment: That's why i mentioned `which is by default turned on via structlog`. if you did ran the code, you will notice the log is keep printed by default